# Visual Studio vs. MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Is it possible to make Visual Studio behave more like MSBuild when building a particular project?

For example, I have some projects which some dependencies like that:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="XXX.vcxproj">
    <SetConfiguration>Platform=Win32</SetConfiguration>
    <Project>{ee60726e-3ae2-4733-b11c-c7f21be51d74}</Project>
  </ProjectReference>
  <ProjectReference Include="XXX.vcxproj">
    <SetConfiguration>Platform=x64</SetConfiguration>
    <Project>{ee60726e-3ae2-4733-b11c-c7f21be51d74}</Project>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

One project is referenced twice, with different settings.  While MSBuild is building both projects, Visual Studio somehow notice that the parent project is depending on project XXX, but only builds configuration selected in Visual Studio.

Alternatively, does somebody know how to specify project dependencies such that the described scenario is possible?

My ideal solution would be that Visual is invoking MSBuild in the exact same way as I do from the command line, may be there is already an extension?

Comment: Use Build > Configuration Manager > Build checkbox to decide what gets built.

Comment: That's not working for this problem, since every project is listed there just once.

Comment: That is not relevant.  Use the Platform combobox in the same dialog to change the what is built per platform.

Comment: That's not working, the project is just build once, not twice (with different settings).

Comment: Keep looking through that menu, it appears you haven't found Build > Batch Build yet.  Press F1 to learn more.

Comment: OK, Batch Build seems to do what I want, but that's very unhandy, in my solution there are around 100 projects, also things have to be specified twice, and there are a couple other draw backs. But thanks anyways.